# iPhone App Store ID for client app

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store

I'm trying to connect my app to facebook, I've filled everything so far, except for the "iPhone App Store ID". I Understand I can get it on iTunes Connect by registering my app. The thing is, my app is for a third party client, he has an apple ID of his own, and he will be the one uploading the app to the Appstore. If I register the app, will that cause my client problems when he tries to upload the app to the Appstore?

I stuck in this problem and not really sure where to go, I already asked my client for an iPhone App Store ID, but I have yet to receive an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using your clients App ID would be the way to go. Otherwise things might get messy...

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little scared of making a big mess and getting in trouble with my client.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the App with your own ID and when required you have to use your client's ID.

Comment: ok, I created my own App, and used the iphone app store ID they gave me, but facebook gave me this error: "Your iPhone App Store ID is invalid because the iTunes App Store reports your app as being unavailable for iPhone and iPod touch.". :s

Comment: In that case do not fill the Facebook "Native iOS Application".
To test it what you needed is the Facebook appid.

Comment: I tried saving the application a few hours later and I didn't get this error. Seems like everything is running smoothly so far.